# Use of italics and BrE single quotation marks

Tags: british-english, writing-style, quotation-marks, emphasis, italics

I'd like to know when to use italics and when to use single quotation marks should be used.  For example:

> The word he was looking for was ‘abjuration’.

vs

> The word he was looking for was *abjuration*.

Comment: The answer by site participant deadrat to the question [So, are single quotes, double quotes, or italics most appropriate here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350149/so-are-single-quotes-double-quotes-or-italics-most-appropriate-here) may be of interest to you. Although the predominant U.S. punctuation style prefers double quotation marks over single ones, you can simply replace the references to double quotation marks (versus italics) with references to single quotation marks (versus italics) to get a pretty good approximation of British punctuation style.

Comment: Questions about punctuation are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) that accords with your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted *The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) to see what a style guide focused on British English preferences had to say about using single quotation marks or using italics in instances involving what *The Chicago Manual of Style* refers to as "words used as words." OGS's guidelines are ... ambivalent.

On the one hand, in section **5.13.1 [Quotation marks:] Names and titles**, OGS has this advice:

> Use quotation marks to enclose an unfamiliar word or phrase, or one to be used in a technical sense. The effect is similar to that  of highlighting a term through italics:
>
> > [Example:] 'Hermeneutics' is the usual term for such interpretation.
> >
> > [Example:] Our subject is the age of Latin literature known as 'Silver'.

But on the other hand, in section **6.2.1 [Italic:] Emphasis and highlighting**, OGS says this:

> Parts of sentences can be highlighted by italics or by quotation marks. Decide which will be clearest and most intelligible to the reader, and apply that style consistently in comparable contexts:
>
> > [Examples:] the letter *z*[;] spell *labour* with a *u*[;] the past tense of *go* is *went*[;] the *do*s and *don't*s
>
> Technical terms and words being introduced, defined, or assigned a special meaning often need to be italicized at first mention:
>
> > [Example:] the doctrine of *determinism*
> >
> > [Example:] the grapes next enter the *crusher-stemmer*
> >
> > [Example:] the outing known as a *wayzgoose* is an old tradition
> >
> > [Example:] here, the piunt-till is a *box* rather than a *deck*

So what rule does OGS recommend that you apply in choosing between 'abjuration' and *abjuration*? "Decide which [you think] will be clearest and most intelligible to the reader, and apply that style consistently in comparable cases." In short, either option is acceptable to Oxford, but be consistent about applying it.